# Numpy: Should I use newaxis or None?

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy one can use the 'newaxis' object in the slicing syntax to create an axis of length one, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
print np.zeros((3,5))[:,np.newaxis,:].shape
# shape will be (3,1,5)
```

The [documentation states](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) that one can also use `None` instead of `newaxis`, the effect is exactly the same.

Is there any reason to choose one over the other? Is there any general preference or style guide? My impression is that `newaxis` is more popular, probably because it is more explicit. So is there any reason why `None` is allowed?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

`None` is allowed because `numpy.newaxis` is merely an alias for `None`.

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.newaxis is None
Out[2]: True
```

The authors probably chose it because they needed a convenient constant, and `None` was available.

As for why you should prefer `newaxis` over `None`: mainly it's because it's more explicit, and partly because someday the `numpy` authors might change it to something other than `None`.  (They're not planning to, and probably won't, but there's no good reason to prefer `None`.)

Comment: They actually say you can use None, though, so they can't change it now:  "The newaxis object can be used in the basic slicing syntax discussed above. None can also be used instead of newaxis."

Comment: Also if you work with people unfamiliar with the details of numpy indexing they seem to go crazy when they see arrays dereferenced by "None"

Comment: One place when `None` is better is optimization of execution speed, it can give a very tiny time benefit. But usually you should prefer `np.newaxis`.

Comment: @Ethunxxx try to `import dis; dis.dis('None')` vs `import dis; dis.dis('np.newaxis')` and see the difference in bytecode. You wouldn't see huge boost, but nevertheless. For future question, `LOAD_CONST` is faster then `LOAD_NAME`.

Comment: Why they just didn't use `newaxis = object()` (or the C-level equivalent) is beyond me...  using `None` is quite error-prone. I had a function with a bug (a bare `return` that was supposed to return a boolean array) and I started getting errors due to shape mismatch. Took me a while to realize that indexing with `None` doesn't simply raise an `IndexError`. If they had used a "fresh" sentinel value I'd avoided 30 mins of trying to make sense of the error...

Comment: Also, don't be tempted to substitute `a[slice(None)]` for `a[None]`.  `slice(None)` means *everything*.  Rather obvious, isn't it?