# Is there a rationale making indexing an array with `None` meaningful regarding changing the shape?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Indexing a NumPy array with `None` increases its number of dimensions, adding an axis with length 1:

```
import numpy
array = numpy.arange(1, 10)
for i in range(4):
    print (array )
    array = array[None]
```

This form is usually found with `None` replaced by its [alias `newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis).

But what is the rationale making indexing with `None` meaningful regarding changing the shape?

Or is it just a convention to use without rational?

Comment: It's a unique value that doesn't have any other use in indexing.

Comment: The same question also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408311/numpy-array-slice-using-none)

Comment: @anurag. Good find, however while the rationale question was asked, it was never answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

Super late response but I figure it could help those searching.

Answer is also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944863/numpy-should-i-use-newaxis-or-none?noredirect=1&lq=1):

The authors of numpy just decided to use 'none' as an alias to newaxis. There is no rational. no english semantic to make this make sense. It's just a word they decided to use.