# Array subtraction and/or reshaping

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, operations

I would like some help with a problem. In Python:

```
a=array([2,2])
b=ones((2,10))
```

I would like to know if there is a function that allows me to subtract b-a to have an array of 2x10 full of -1.

I can do it one with 1D arrays, I just wanted to know if it is possible to do with 2D arrays.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new dimension to `a`:

```
b - a[:,None]
```

where `a[:,None]` becomes `array([[2], [2]])`, a 2x1 array which you can substract from a 2x10 array and get a 2x10 array full of -1.

Comment: A bit late to this, but instead of `None` you can use [`numpy.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944863/numpy-should-i-use-newaxis-or-none

Answer (score 0):

You want to have an array of 2x10 full of -1.

Why don't you just do like this:

```
b = np.ones((2, 10)) * -1

array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]])
```

Comment: Because the question is about adding and subtracting (check the title)

Comment: @Leon palafox: The title says Array subtraction and/or reshaping.

Comment: I did not see anything about creating arrays :)