# Remove mean from numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix `A` where the data is organised column-vector-vise i.e `A[:,0]` is the first data vector, `A[:,1]` is the second and so on. I wanted to know whether there was a more elegant way to zero out the mean from this data. I am currently doing it via a `for` loop:

```
mean=A.mean(axis=1)
for k in range(A.shape[1]):
    A[:,k]=A[:,k]-mean
```

So does numpy provide a function to do this? Or can it be done more efficiently another way?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As is typical, you can do this a number of ways. Each of the approaches below works by adding a dimension to the `mean` vector, making it a 4 x 1 array, and then NumPy's broadcasting takes care of the rest. Each approach creates a view of `mean`, rather than a deep copy. The first approach (i.e., using `newaxis`) is likely preferred by most, but the other methods are included for the record.

In addition to the approaches below, see also [ovgolovin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423344/937870), which uses a NumPy matrix to avoid the need to reshape `mean` altogether.

For the methods below, we start with the following code and example array `A`.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]])
mean = A.mean(axis=1)
```

## Using [`numpy.newaxis`](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#newaxis)

```
>>> A - mean[:, np.newaxis]
array([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.]])
```

## Using `None`

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) states that `None` can be used instead of `newaxis`. This is because

```
>>> np.newaxis is None
True
```

Therefore, the following accomplishes the task.

```
>>> A - mean[:, None]
array([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.]])
```

That said, `newaxis` is clearer and should be preferred. Also, a case can be made that `newaxis` is more future proof. See also: [Numpy: Should I use newaxis or None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944863/numpy-should-i-use-newaxis-or-none)

## Using [`ndarray.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape)

```
>>> A - mean.reshape((mean.shape[0]), 1)
array([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.]])
```

## Changing [`ndarray.shape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) directly

You can alternatively change the shape of `mean` directly.

```
>>> mean.shape = (mean.shape[0], 1)
>>> A - mean
array([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: The usual way to express this kind of reshape in NumPy is to use [`np.newaxis`](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#newaxis): `A - mean[:, np.newaxis]`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Updated the answer to use `np.newaxis`. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Note that `None` can also be used (i.e., `A - mean[:, None]`, see [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis)). This is because `numpy.newaxis` is `None`, but `np.newaxis` is clearer and is probably more future proof (also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944863/numpy-should-i-use-newaxis-or-none).

Comment: This is one of the many reasons that numpy rocks.  in Matlab, the command would be: bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A, 2)).  I think "A - mean(A, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]" is a lot easier to read and remember.  Also, note that np.newaxis is None

Comment: Another way is to use the `keepdims=True` argument to `.mean()`. Default behavior for `.mean()` is to remove the dimension that you mean over (given by `axis` argument). `keepdims=True` stops it from doing that.


    `>>> import numpy as np`

    `A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`

    `mean = A.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)`

    `A = A - mean`

Comment: I don't know why you'd ever want to call a variable the name of a common function `mean`

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `matrix` instead of `array`. Then you won't need to reshape:

```
>>> A = np.matrix([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]])
>>> m = A.mean(axis=1)
>>> A - m
matrix([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
        [-1.,  0.,  1.],
        [-1.,  0.,  1.],
        [-1.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: I didn't know matrices did that.  +1.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. `pylab.demean`:

```
In [1]: X = scipy.rand(2,3)

In [2]: X.mean(axis=1)
Out[2]: array([ 0.42654669,  0.65216704])

In [3]: Y = pylab.demean(X, axis=1)

In [4]: Y.mean(axis=1)
Out[4]: array([  1.85037171e-17,   0.00000000e+00])
```

Source:

```
In [5]: pylab.demean??
Type:           function
Base Class:     <type 'function'>
String Form:    <function demean at 0x38492a8>
Namespace:      Interactive
File:           /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/mlab.py
Definition:     pylab.demean(x, axis=0)
Source:
def demean(x, axis=0):
    "Return x minus its mean along the specified axis"
    x = np.asarray(x)
    if axis == 0 or axis is None or x.ndim <= 1:
        return x - x.mean(axis)
    ind = [slice(None)] * x.ndim
    ind[axis] = np.newaxis
    return x - x.mean(axis)[ind]
```

Comment: Steve, could you please also add the modules that you imported?

Comment: In this answer, only `scipy` and `pylab`.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like some of these answers are pretty old, I just tested this on numpy 1.13.3:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,1,3],[1,0,4],[1,2,2]])
>>> a
array([[1, 1, 3],
       [1, 0, 4],
       [1, 2, 2]])
>>> a = a - a.mean(axis=0)
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., -1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
```

I think this is much cleaner and simpler. Have a try and let me know if this is somehow inferior than the other answers.