# Numpy broadcasting sliced arrays and vectors

Tags: python, numpy

Given three numpy arrays: one multidimensional array `x`, one vector `y` with trailing singleton dimension, and one vector `z` without trailing singleton dimension,

```
x = np.zeros((M,N))
y = np.zeros((M,1))
z = np.zeros((M,))
```

the behaviour of broadcast operations changes depending on vector representation and context:

```
x[:,0] = y      # error cannot broadcast from shape (M,1) into shape (M)
x[:,0] = z      # OK

x[:,0] += y     # error non-broadcastable output with shape (M) doesn't match 
                # broadcast shape(M,M)
x[:,0] += z     # OK

x - y           # OK
x - z           # error cannot broadcast from shape (M,N) into shape (M)
```

I realize I can do the following:

```
x - z[:,None]   # OK
```

but I don't understand what this explicit notation buys me. It certainly doesn't buy readability. I don't understand why the expression `x - y` is OK, but `x - z` is ambiguous.

**Why does Numpy treat vectors with or without trailing singleton dimensions differently?**

edit: The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) states that: *two dimensions are compatible when they are equal, or one of them is 1*, but `y` and `z` are both functionally `M x 1` vectors, since an `M x 0` vector doesn't contain any elements.

Comment: A key point is that `x[:,0]` is 1d.  `x[:,[0]]` is (M,1).  `z[:]=y` probably gives the same error.

Comment: `z` can be reshaped to (M,1) or (1,M) without copying.  But functionally it is closer to (1,M), because of the automatic extension at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convention is that broadcasting will insert singleton dimensions at the beginning of an array's shape. This makes it convenience to perform operations over the last dimensions of an array, so `(x.T - z).T` should work.

If it were to automatically decide which axis of `x` was matched by `z`, an operation like `x - z` would result in an error if and only if `N == M`, making code harder to test. So the convention allows some convenience, while being robust to some error.

If you don't like the `z[:, None]` shorthand, perhaps you find `z[:, np.newaxis]` clearer.

For an assignment like `x[:,0] = y` to work, you can use `x[:,0:1] = y` instead.

Comment: Can you give an example of where prepending singleton dimensions is useful? A common operation I want to perform is to subtract the column mean from a matrix, but the most intuitive approach `x -= np.mean(x, axis=1)` doesn't actually work as one would hope.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Numpy **matrix** interface as opposed to the array interface yields the [desired broadcasting behaviours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423051/remove-mean-from-numpy-matrix/8423344#8423344):

```
x = np.asmatrix(np.zeros((M,N)))
y = np.asmatrix(np.zeros((M,1)))

x[:,0] = y              # OK
x[:,0] = y[:,0]         # OK
x[:,0] = y[:,0:1]       # OK
x[:,0] += y             # OK
x - y                   # OK
x - np.mean(x, axis=0)  # OK
x - np.mean(x, axis=1)  # OK
```

Comment: On the other hand, introduces all sorts of other problems. Matrix is almost always a source of difficult to find bugs. Take, for example, the `*` operator performs matrix multiplication, not element-wise. If you feed it to a function expecting an array, you are screwed.

Answer (score 0):

One benefit of treating `(M,1)` and `(M,)` differently is to enable you to specify what dimensions to align and what dimensions to broadcast

Say you have:

```
a = np.arange(4)
b = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
# i.e a = array([0, 1, 2, 3])
# i.e b = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#   [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#   [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#   [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

When you do `c = a + b`, `a` and `b` will be aligned in `axis=1` and `a` will be broadcasted along `axis=0`:

```
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
   [0, 1, 2, 3],
   [0, 1, 2, 3],
   [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

But what if you want to align `a` and `b` in `axis=0` and broadcast in `axis=1` ?

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
   [1, 1, 1, 1],
   [2, 2, 2, 2],
   [3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

`(M,1)` vs `(M,)` difference enables you to specify which dimension to align and broadcast.

(i.e if `(M,1)` and `(M,)` are treated the same, how do you tell numpy you want to broadcast on `axis=1`?)

Comment: My mistake was in approaching numpy arrays from an algebraic perspective, rather than as general-purpose containers. In the cases you highlighted above, `c = a.T + b` and `c = a + b` where `a.shape == (M,1)` would broadcast in a way that intuitively makes sense to me. It's a difference in philosophy that I'm trying to understand by enquiring why particular decisions were made in the design of numpy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are right in **2D** `a.T + b` could specify the broadcast preference, but it would be really hard to apply it for higher dimension operations. I guess numpy's approach is more general.