# Operations with numpy array elements

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Have a numpy array which was created from pandas values.

It looks like this:

```
array([[ 230.1,   37.8,   69.2],
      [  44.5,   39.3,   45.1],
      [  17.2,   45.9,   69.3],
      [ 151.5,   41.3,   58.5],
      [ 180.8,   10.8,   58.4]])
```

How can I subtract the np.mean() of it from every single entry of this array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look at the numpy documentation?

Comment: I believe you will find what you are looking for in the keyword argument `axis`

Comment: look up "broadcasting" ( http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html )  it gets complex pretty quick, so just stick to the basic examples for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `-`:

```
a = array([[ 230.1,   37.8,   69.2],
  [  44.5,   39.3,   45.1],
  [  17.2,   45.9,   69.3],
  [ 151.5,   41.3,   58.5],
  [ 180.8,   10.8,   58.4]])
a -= a.mean()
```

Comment: as a side note, this subtracts the OVERALL mean from ALL values.  If you wish to subtract the mean of each column from each column, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423051/remove-mean-from-numpy-matrix