# Concatenate two numpy arrays in the 4th dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays with three dimensions (3 x 4 x 5) and I want to concatenate them so the result has four dimensions (3 x 4 x 5 x 2). In Matlab, this can be done with `cat(4, a, b)`, but not in Numpy.

For example:

```
a = ones((3,4,5))
b = ones((3,4,5))
c = concatenate((a,b), axis=3) # error!
```

To clarify, I wish `c[:,:,:,0]` and `c[:,:,:,1]` to correspond to the original two arrays.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What about

```
c = np.stack((a,b), axis=3)
```

Comment: This function was added in numpy version 1.10 and make this operation more elegant.

Answer (score 29):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((3,4,5))
b = np.ones((3,4,5))
c = np.concatenate((a[...,np.newaxis],b[...,np.newaxis]),axis=3)
```

Comment: Accepting this one for being slightly more readable. Plus it releaved me of my ignorance of the `...` operator.

Comment: If you have a sequence of arrays that you want to stack this way you can use: `c = np.concatenate([aux[..., np.newaxis] for aux in sequence_of_arrays], axis=3)`

Comment: More generally, you can use `axis=-1` regardless of the number of dimensions in the original array.

Answer (score 14):

How about the following:

```
c = concatenate((a[:,:,:,None],b[:,:,:,None]), axis=3)
```

This gives a (3 x 4 x 5 x 2) array, which I believe is laid out in the manner you require.

Here, `None` is synonymous to `np.newaxis`: [Numpy: Should I use newaxis or None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944863/numpy-should-i-use-newaxis-or-none)

**edit** As suggested by @Joe Kington, the code could be cleaned up a little bit by using an ellipsis:

```
c = concatenate((a[...,None],b[...,None]), axis=3)
```

Comment: beat me by a couple of seconds. . .dammit :-) I'll blame it on typing out `np.newaxis`, instead of `None` +1 to you

Comment: @JoshAdel: LOL, but you've saved on not having to type all those annoying colons! :-)

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer above is great.  But I'll add the following because I'm a math dork and it's a nice use of the fact that `a.shape` is `a.T.shape[::-1]`...i.e. taking a transpose reverses the order of the indices of a numpy array.  So if you have your building blocks in an array called blocks, then the solution above is:

```
new = np.concatenate([block[..., np.newaxis] for block in blocks],
                     axis=len(blocks[0].shape))
```

but you could also do

```
new2 = np.array([block.T for block in blocks]).T
```

which I think reads more cleanly.  It's worth noting that the already-accepted answer runs more quickly:

```
%%timeit
new = np.concatenate([block[..., np.newaxis] for block in blocks],
                     axis=len(blocks[0].shape))
1000 loops, best of 3: 321 µs per loop
```

while

```
%%timeit
new2 = np.array([block.T for block in blocks]).T
1000 loops, best of 3: 407 µs per loop
```

Comment: That's a lovely, creative solution.

Comment: This is what I needed and it is agnostic of the total number of dimensions for any numpy array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
 c = numpy.array([a,b])
```

Though it would be nice if it worked your way, too.

Comment: I tried that, but it results in a (2 x 3 x 4 x 5) array. Close, but not quite.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily the most elegant, but I've used variations of

```
c = rollaxis(array([a,b]), 0, 4)
```

in the past.