# Concatenating numpy arrays of different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I have several **N**-dimensional arrays of different shapes and want to combine them into a new **(N+1)**-dimensional array, where the new axis has a length corresponding to the number of initial N-d arrays.

[This answer is sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898471/concatenate-two-numpy-arrays-in-the-4th-dimension) if the original arrays are all the same shape; however, it does not work if they have different shapes.

I don't really want to reshape the arrays to a congruent size and fill with empty elements due to the subsequent analysis I need to perform on the final array.

Specifically, I have four 4D arrays. One of the things I want to do with the resulting 5D array is plot parts of the four arrays on the same matplotlib figure. Obviously I could plot each one separately, however soon I will have more than four 4D arrays and am looking for a dynamic solution.

Comment: You cannot put arrays of different shape in one array without filling the gaps with 0 or other numbers.

Comment: Just put the arrays in a Python list.  Then you can iterate over them to plot them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I was writing this, Sven gave the same answer in the comments...

Put the arrays in a python list in the following manner:

```
5d_list = []
5d_list.append(4D_array_1)
5d_list.append(4D_array_2)
...
```

Then you can unpack them:

```
for 4d_array in 5d_list:
    #plot 4d array on figure
```