# Convert multiple arrays to single array with new dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4 different numpy array's (2Dimension) and each array have the size (112,20).
How can I convert (concatenate) them, to one array with 3 Dimension and the size of (112, 20, 4).
Thanks for your support!

Comment: `c = np.stack((a, b, c, d), axis=2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate two numpy arrays in the 4th dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898471/concatenate-two-numpy-arrays-in-the-4th-dimension)

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.stack((arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4), axis=2)`:

```
arr1 = np.zeros((2,5))
arr2 = np.ones((2,5))
arr3 = np.ones((2,5))*2
arr4 = np.ones((2,5))*3

v = np.stack((arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4), axis=2)
```

`v.shape` returns `(2, 5, 4)`

Output:

```
array([[[0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.]],

       [[0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.]]])
```

Comment: add an `axis` parameter to get his desired shape.  I like to 'prove' my answers with an example.

Comment: I was a bit lazy, you're absolutely right

Comment: @PeterHacker can you 'accept' the answer and upvote? :D