# How to push the for-loop down to numpy

Tags: python, numpy, kriging

I have the following piece of code doing exactly what i want (it is part of a kriging method). But the problem is that it goes too slow, and i wish to know if there is any option to push the for-loop down to numpy? If i push out the numpy.sum, and use the axis argument there, it speeds up a little bit, but apparently that is not the bottleneck. Any ideas on how i can push down the forloop to numpy to speed it up, or other ways to speed it up?)

```
# n = 2116
print GRZVV.shape  # (16309, 2116)
print GinvVV.shape  # (2117, 2117) 
VVg = numpy.empty((GRZVV.shape[0]))

for k in xrange(GRZVV.shape[0]):
    GRVV = numpy.empty((n+1, 1))
    GRVV[n, 0] = 1
    GRVV[:n, 0] = GRZVV[k, :]
    EVV = numpy.array(GinvVV * GRVV)  # GinvVV is numpy.matrix
    VVg[k] = numpy.sum(EVV[:n, 0] * VV)
```

I posted the dimensions of the ndarrays n matrix to clear some stuff out

edit: shape of VV is 2116

Comment: If `VV.shape == (16309,)`, how can you mulitply it by `EVV[:n, 0]` which has shape `(n,)`?

Comment: Maybe the last line of your loop should have `EVV[:n, 0] * VV[k]`, which seems to be what @Jaime's answer assumes.

Comment: @askewchan shape was 2116, was a bit confused there, i edited it in,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following in place of your loop over k (runtime ~3s):

```
tmp = np.concatenate((GRZVV, np.ones((16309,1),dtype=np.double)), axis=1)
EVV1 = np.dot(GinvVV, tmp.T)
#Changed line below based on *askewchan's* recommendation
VVg1 = np.sum(np.multiply(EVV1[:n,:],VV[:,np.newaxis]), axis=0)
```

Comment: This gives the same result as @usethedeathstar's code, and runs 15x faster on my machine.

Comment: No need for the tile call, as the `np.multiply` broadcasts. Change it to: `VVg1 = np.sum(np.multiply(EVV1[:n,:],VV[:,np.newaxis]), axis=0)` for a small speedup.

Comment: +1  Much, much faster than `np.einsum` for large arrays, not sure I understand why...

Comment: slight issue: VVg1 is still a numpy.matrix instead of ndarray? is this affecting the np.multiply or so? I assume/hope not, or should i after the np.dot do a cast to numpy.array on the EVV1?

Comment: Another side question: what is the difference between [:,numpy.newaxis] and using [:,None] ? And why the numpy.multiply instead of just using "*" ? And the speedup is 12 times (which is NICE)

Comment: Difference between np.newaxis and None --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944863/numpy-should-i-use-newaxis-or-none

Comment: `np.multiply` was used to do element-wise multiplication in the np.matrix (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u)

Comment: @joelVroom so basically i can cast it to an ndarray again and be done with it after the numpy.dot?

Answer (score 3):

You are basically taking each row of `GRZVV`, appending a 1 at the end, multiplying it with `GinvVV`, then adding up all the elements in the vector. If you weren't doing the "append 1" thing, you could do it all with no loops as:

```
VVg = np.sum(np.dot(GinvVV[:, :-1], GRZVV.T), axis=-1) * VV
```

or even:

```
VVg = np.einsum('ij,kj->k', GinvVV[:, :-1], GRZVV) * VV
```

How do we handle that extra 1? Well, the resulting vector coming from the matrix multiplication would be incremented by the corresponding value in `GinvVV[:, -1]`, and when you add them all, the value will be incremented by `np.sum(GinvVV[:, -1])`. So we can simply calculate this once and add it to all the items in the return vector:

```
VVg = (np.einsum('ij,kj->k', GinvVV[:-1, :-1], GRZVV) + np.sum(GinvVV[:-1, -1])) * VV
```

---

The above code works if `VV` is a scalar. If it is an array of shape `(n,)`, then the following will work:

```
GinvVV = np.asarray(GinvVV)
VVgbis = (np.einsum('ij,kj->k', GinvVV[:-1, :-1]*VV[:, None], GRZVV) +
          np.dot(GinvVV[:-1, -1], VV))
```

Comment: With @usethedeathstar's edit, `VV.shape` is now 2116, so doesn't broadcast in your solution (since `Wg.shape` is 16309)

Comment: Figured it was a scalar. With a full array, not collapsing the array till the end, as in Joel's answer, is much faster than the above for large arrays.